# Why my ServerSocket is not displaying the output from socket?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program by Socket Programming in which I send messages from
client and the server displays them.
But the server is only displaying the words only after I type "STOP".
Its not showing it simultaneously as I press enter.

Also why i have to explicitly write `import java.net.Socket;` and `import java.net.ServerSocket;` because `java.net.*;` is giving me errors.

Here is my Client's code :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;


 public class SocketTest {



public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 6666);
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = "";
    while(!(str = sc.nextLine()).equals("STOP"))
    writer.write(str);

    writer.close();
    socket.close();
  } 
}
```

Here is my Server's code :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.io.*;


public class ServerTest{



public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(6666);
    Socket s = socket.accept();
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(reader));
    System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
    sc.close();
    socket.close();
 }  
}
```

Comment: Now i'm not even getting output after typing STOP.
I guess whatever i typed was still in the buffer and is only reaching server when i type STOP

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

Answer (score 0):

When you call `write()` you actually write to a buffer. It flushes the content if the buffer is full. And in your case it flushes when you type STOP and close() is called which flushes before closing. To write instantly you need to call `flush()` method. And add new line character at the end of string.

```
 while(!(str = sc.nextLine()).equals("STOP")) {
        writer.write(str + "\n");
        writer.flush();
    }
```

Comment: so flushing it just after writing?

Comment: Yes. Other wise it will flush if buffer is full or when closed.

Comment: Take both in curly brachets after while statement. Otherwise only write will work in while. while(!(str = sc.nextLine()).equals("STOP")){ writer.write();writer.flush()}

Comment: yeah i'm doing that only

Comment: `while(!(str = sc.nextLine()).equals("STOP")){
  writer.write(str);
  writer.flush();
  }`

Comment: is everything fine with my Server?

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop does not have a starting brace. So the while loop basically eats all input until the input string is "STOP".

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 6666);
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = "";
    while(!(str = sc.nextLine()).equals("STOP")){ //The while loop's starting brace is missing
    writer.write(str);

    writer.close();
    socket.close();
  } 
}
```

You will have to add another closing brace at the end for the whole class definition as well.